# Detect an attached DependencyProperty from code-behind in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a class named `MenuItemHelper` which attach a `GroupName` property to my `MenuItem`s in WPF (I get this from [here](http://www.bradcunningham.net/2009/09/grouping-and-checkboxes-in-wpf.html)).

How do I set or get it's value from code-behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods for doing it should be in the MenuItemHelper class:

```
MenuItemHelper.SetGroupName(someMenuItem, "a group name");
string groupName = MenuItemHelper.GetGroupName(someMenuItem);
```